# Client socket not receiving in Python code

Tags: python, sockets

I have a python program that is supposed to connect to a server and receive specially formatted packets, that I can test and filter out. I can connect to the server, but I can't see that I am receiving any packets - though I am sure that I am. I don't know how to debug this.

```
class client:
    def __init__(self, host ='127.0.0.1', port=12345):    
        self.host = host    
        self.port = port    
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))    

    def get_next_event(self):    
        pkt_size_data = self.sock.recv(4)    
        # on the above line I am not getting any response, the client just waits for something....    
        pkt_size = self.size_struct.unpack((pkt_size_data))[0]   #I never get here    
        pkt_data= self.sock.recv(pkt_size)    
#(  get_next_event is called from an infinite loop )
```

I am using VS2010 - setting breakpoints - looking at my objects using VS2010 tools - are there some tools I can use to debug and see why I am not getting any response from the recv?

Any idea why I am not getting any response ?

Comment: "though I am sure that I am" - how do you sure about that? What's the evidence?

Comment: This program has been used by others(I have changed what the server is sending, I am fairly - theoretically- sure that the packets being sent and received are of the same type - but I am sure that the server is sending... something.
I am trying to modify the client but I am trying to understand it first - and I can't get it to work.
The server is sending packets continuously...
Well even if it isn't, I would like to be able to SEE somehow what is going on.
Es

Comment: try to call outside the infinite loop, just once. See what you get. Try to call it with bufsize less than 4, say 1. See what you get. However, for now this looks like you don't really receive anything.

Comment: That is one major part of the question - how do I look to find out what am I receiving - if anything ?

Comment: Thank you izhak, I have tried both options, I still have a blank screen.
Is there any debug tool - either inside VS2010 or some command line tool - that can tell me if I am receiving anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sniffer to see what's going on. Try http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: I don't know how to compare the traffic with or without the server running to see if the server is really sending anything. I have stepped through the server code, and it seems that it does... Wireshark shows me (as the only thing that I can see without any tools) that when the server is running, there are quite a few ICMP messages and SNMP get-request, get-next-request, get-response (the content doesn't make any sense)

Comment: You have to to capture packets on the interface you server and client are communicating through, run the server and client and then filter the traffic. For you example it would be TCP connections for 127.0.0.1 port 12345